# href in Django for guest visitor to a user profile page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<userid>\d+)', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

in the urls.py

And I have

```
def profile(request, userid):
```

What should I have for a button's href for guest visitors to be able to view the user profile page?

```
href="/accounts/profile/<userid>"
```

or

```
href="{% url 'users:profile' user.id %}"
```

I can't get neither of the above working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ran into this issue a few days ago.

```
{% url 'users:profile' user.id as profile_link %}
<a href="{{ profile_link }}">Profile</a>
```

Also for the future, your example did not include single quotes between the namespace and name of the url. You should have `{% url 'users:namehere' %}`, not `{% url users:namehere %}`

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question. Can you explain a bit why it works that way. In the doc, it just says "If you’d like to retrieve a URL without displaying it, you can use a slightly different call:"

Comment: There's no reason to use the separate tag or save it as the profile_link variable here. OP's final snippet should work fine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The final snippet does not work if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Your approach does not raise an exception but the the links don't generate url.

Comment: Hmm. If it's not raising an exception, then it's safe to assume that your namespace and name for the URL both exist. What version of Django are you running?